How to build a Cargo.lock file for a package within a workspace
When I cargo publish from the package directory in my workspace, I get:
error: Source directory was modified by build.rs during cargo publish. Build scripts should not modify anything outside of OUT_DIR.
Added: {workspace_dir}/target/package/{package_name}-{version}/Cargo.lock

To proceed despite this, pass the `--no-verify` flag.

I've tried using cargo generate-lockfile from the package directory, including with the --lockfile-path, but it keeps generating a lockfile for the entire workspace. How do I generate the lockfile for just this one package?
I tried to run cargo package and commit the lock file back into the package folder, but I get the same error. I confirmed that the file is the same, by checking that diff {package_name}/Cargo.lock target/package/{package_name}-{version}/Cargo.lock is empty.
I would also accept a solution that stops generating the Cargo.lock file, since this package is a library without a binary. Although I understand that Rust is moving toward always publishing Cargo.lock, so it's slightly less preferred.

Do you mess with the Cargo.lock in your own build script? I'm a bit confused whether you're doing something out-of-the ordinary or if this is a bug in cargo publish? You should not have to do anything with Cargo.lock

It's possible shadow-rs is creating the .lock file? https://github.com/ethereum/trin/blob/c93e129dcfa006c5b40f673b7c988e923ddeb6b6/ethportal-api/build.rs
